# How to get array of json objects rather than mongoose documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I do the `.find` operation like the following:

```
Collection.find({name: 'Erik'}, function (err, docs) {
   // do momething
});
```

'docs' variable is populated with an array of fully functional mongoose documents. But I need to get an array of pure JSON objects.

I know I can loop through the 'docs' array by forEach and get an objects by using .toJSON() method. Does mongoose support the feature, I'm interested?

Comment: An array of plain JavaScript objects

Answer (score 43):

If you're using Mongoose 3.x you can use the [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) query option to do this:

```
Collection.find({name: 'Erik'}).lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
    // docs are plain javascript objects instead of model instances
});
```

Comment: Note that `lean` is not the same as `toJSON` as it returns a raw dump from Mongo (meaning no `virtuals` are included). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18383080/529829) for more info

Comment: wow, they couldn't have made this more difficult to find.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 10):

```
.exec(function(err, docs){
    docs= docs.map(o => o.toObject());
```

This will include **virtuals** and **getters**

Answer (score 0):

Map through results and convert each to JS object:

```
const result = await model.find({some: 'query'});
return result.map((r) => r.toObject());
```