# mongoose lean query, virtuals not showing

Tags: mongoose

I have the following schema set up on mongoose, Im using version 3.6.17:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    video: { type: String, default: ''},
    cover: { type: String, default: ''},
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    lastUpdate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }, { autoIndex: true, toObject: { virtuals: true }, toJSON: { virtuals: true } });
```

And the following virtuals:

```
PostSchema.virtual('replied').get(function () {
    return false;
});

PostSchema.virtual('cover_url').get(function () {
    return config.cover.server + this.cover;
});

PostSchema.virtual('video_url').get(function () {
    return config.video.server + this.video;
});
```

When I do an aggregate query:

```
Post.aggregate(  { $match:  { replyTo: { $ne: "" }, author: user._id,  draft: false } },
                    { $project: {
                            _id: 1,
                            video: 1,
                            video_url: 1,
                            cover: 1,
                            cover_url: 1,
                            createdAt: 1,
                            lastUpdate: 1,
                            Ireplied : { $not: "$replied"} }
                          }, function ( ) ....
```

At this point the virtuals return but they return with the attribute this.cover or this.video undefined.

And when I do a Post.findOne(..).lean().populate(...) etc, I dont get the virtuals at all, neither with a Post.find().lean().populate(...)

Am I missing something on the Post schema, to be able to return the virtuals, or am I doing something wrong?
And why with the aggregate operation the virtuals return the value "this.cover" as undefined?

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`lean` queries return raw `MongoDB` driver response as a plain `js` object. So, there are no `getters`, `setters`, `virtuals` or other "Mongoose magic" in it. See [Api docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) for more info.

The point of `lean` queries is to return your objects as fast as possible. If you need `virtuals` - use ordinary Mongoose queries.

As for aggregation, it's 100% `MongoDB` feature and Mongoose can't control it. So, when you calling `aggregate` from Mongoose it works the same as `aggregate` in `MongoDB` console. `aggregate` can't operate with virtuals, because there are no such fields in your database. Mongoose can't even cast your aggregation query according to your schema (like it's doing with `findOneAndUpdate` arguments), because aggregation changes the shape of the document on each step. See [Mongoose API Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) and [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for more info.

Comment: Hi, actually Im getting the virtuals and actually modifying them with the aggregate query and the normal query, I did took the lean part out and everything works, but Im getting a weird duplicate _id and id field from the populated fields, and also getting the cover_url and video_url on the populated fields which I dont want, how can I remove those fields, in the population select option Im not requesting those!

Answer (score 4):

i found a solution you can use mongoose-lean-virtuals plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-lean-virtuals