# How do I return all documents from mongodb with mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

A regular mongoose find does not seem to send back documents as json. Eeach doc is my database is a simple object.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a170f0736435d829d97c17"),
    "ip" : "74.208.147.41",
    "domain" : "test.com",
    "wp" : "4.4.2",
    "host_name" : "Web03",
    "hosted" : 1.0
}
```

I'm assuming it's because mongoose does not respond with json but an array of documents I believe. But how can I map these to send back json and eventually loop over in view with angular.

Here's my get route

```
router.get('/api/sites', function(req, res, next) {
  Site.find({}, function(err, sites) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      return res.json({sites: sites});
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** 
It definitely seems to be the mongoose find query. If I pass in a value for the "ip" field to query by(ex: Site.find({ip: '74.208.147.41'})..., I get a response. When I pass no values in, I don't get a response.

Here's my model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var sitesEntrySchema = new Schema({
    ip: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    domain: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    wp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    host_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    hosted: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
});

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
var Site = mongoose.model('Site', sitesEntrySchema, 'site');
module.exports = Site;
```

**EDIT 8/10/16:**
Finally updated my version of mongoose and the find query worked.

**EDIT 2/01/17:**
Explictly defining collection to use was the real issue. This thread helped me:
[Mongoose always returning an empty array NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183611/mongoose-always-returning-an-empty-array-nodejs)

Comment: Possible duplicate. Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210870/how-to-get-array-of-json-objects-rather-than-mongoose-documents

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk thanks! I've seen this but after enabling mongoose errors to print to the console. I see this; sites.find({}) { fields: undefined }  so I think mongoose is not even executing querying.

Comment: @Calrocks That's the expected debug output when you don't select specific fields.

Comment: @JohnnyHK oh ok. Thank you. That's good to know. Any idea why I don't get a response failed request when I hit the above get route?

Comment: @Calrocks It's not clear from you question what's not working. Can you [edit] your question to provide more details?

Comment: @JohnnyHK made an edit. def seems to be mongoose query.

Comment: @Calrocks Hmm...that doesn't really make sense. What does `console.log(sites)` show in the "query all" case?

Comment: @JohnnyHK exactly. Finally decided to update my version of mongoose to the latest and query suddenly worked! Thanks so much for taking the time to try and help tho. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/api/sites", async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const sites = await Site.find();
    res.json({ sites });
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find

The documentation says .find() takes 3 parameters and it doesn't mention a callback function to be one of its parameters(doesn't take callback function). And the above code worked fine for me.